# Phone gap error remote build android

Tags: android, cordova

im have some trouble when use build remote, before it error im success build it remote, but when im build it again there some trouble

> error : app 625456 not found

this the screenshot

[image: error build]
im need some solution for this

Comment: What did you do so far?   Need more information... Did you build it once, and deleted it on build.phonegap.com ?

Comment: im add some button back for the header,
yes im delete before project in build.phonegap.com and im try build it again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/122

Check out this post, and do the following.

Another thing is...

If you created your app `phonegap create hello`, and you then deleted that app, because you only can have 1 private app.  Then you cant just rebuild.

You will have to create the project again with the `phonegap create` command.